# For the network shown in the figure, draw the corresponding Thévenin equivalent circuit and establish its parameters VT and RT

Tags: voltage, amplifier, resistance, thevenin

[image]

I can't find any examples online similar to this format, please help!
Attempt: RT = (2*5)/(2+5) = 10/7 = 1.429 k-ohms
VT = 8V + 8V = 16 V
Do you ignore the center resistor and just add the voltages together?

Comment: @brhans here was my attempt: VT = 8V + 8V = 16V; RT = (2*5)/(2 + 5) = 10/7 = 1.429 k-ohms

Comment: refer to your course material and speak to your instructor .... you may have missed something in your previous lessons

Comment: Your attempt is incorrect for VT. Here's a hint on how to find that: If you took a multimeter and measured the voltage between A and B, what would your multimeter tell you?

Comment: @KingDuken would it be 8 V as the other 8 V is solely channeled to the two 2 k-ohm resistors?

Comment: Just look at the top half for a moment...what is 'a' in relation to the upper voltage source?  Hopefully you can figure it out from there.

Comment: @evildemonic would Va be represented as a voltage divider; Va = 2/(2+2)*8 = 4V? And then, the current would travel through the 5 k-ohm resistor, and that would be 2mA*5k-ohm = 10V?

Comment: Yes to the voltage divider part and the 4V.  You don't need to worry about current at this point, so I don't agree with the 10V part.  You know what 'a' is in relation to the common port, and you should be able to see that 'b' in relation to the common port is just the 8V of the voltage source.

Answer (score 0):

When a and b are open, the two 2K resistors in the upper circuit form a voltage divider. When a and b are short, the short current flowing back through 5K resistor. Does this help?